# Custom::LambdaTrigger resource is stuck at CREATE_IN_PROGRESS while using Cloud Formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a stack using AWS Cloud Formation. I have a Custom::LambdaTrigger resource which is causing the problem.

The resource gets stuck at CREATE_IN_PROGRESS for a very long time. Refer the image below:

[image]

Following the corresponding cloud formation code:

```
 "ApiDeployerTrigger": {
            "Type": "Custom::LambdaTrigger",
            "Properties": {
                "ServiceToken": {
                    "Fn::GetAtt": [
                        "ApiDeployer",
                        "Arn"
                    ]
                },
                "RestApiId": {
                    "Ref": "ApiGateway"
                },
                "StageName": "v1",
                "SeqNo": {
                    "Ref": "PackageVersion"
                }
            },
            "DependsOn": [
                "ApiGateway"
            ]
        }
```

Then, it fails to create and the rollback happens.

[image]

And then the rollback also fails

[image]

Update:
I looked into the CloudWatch logs. I am getting the following error:

[image]

Following is the code for creating the lambda function:

```
        "ApiDeployer": {
            "Properties": {
                "Code": {
                    "ZipFile": {
                        "Fn::Join": [
                            "\n", [
                                "var aws = require('aws-sdk');",
                                "var response = require('cfn-response');",
                                "exports.handler = function(event, context, callback){",
                                "console.log(event);",
                                "try{",
                                " var apigateway = new aws.APIGateway();",
                                " if (event.RequestType == 'Update' || event.RequestType == 'Create'){",
                                "   var params = {};",
                                "   params.restApiId = event.ResourceProperties.RestApiId;",
                                "   params.stageName = event.ResourceProperties.StageName;",
                                "   apigateway.createDeployment(params, function(err, data) {",
                                "   if (err){",
                                "     console.log(err);",
                                "     response.send(event, context, response.FAILED, err);",
                                "     callback(null);",
                                "   }else {",
                                "     console.log(data);",
                                "     var id = event.PhysicalResourceId ? event.PhysicalResourceId : 'Deployment'+new Date().toISOString().replace(/[-T\\:.Z]/ig,'');",
                                "     response.send(event, context, response.SUCCESS, data, id);",
                                "     callback(null, 'Deployed API');",
                                "    }",
                                "   });",
                                " }else{",
                                "  response.send(event, context, response.SUCCESS, {}, event.PhysicalResourceId);",
                                "  allback(null);",
                                " }",
                                "} catch(e) {",
                                "  console.log(e);",
                                "  response.send(event, context, response.FAILED, e);",
                                "  callback(null);",
                                "}",
                                "};"
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "Handler": "index.handler",
                "Role": {
                    "Fn::GetAtt": [
                        "ApiLambdaExecutionRole",
                        "Arn"
                    ]
                },
                "Runtime": "nodejs10.x",
                "Timeout": 60
            },
            "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function"
        }
```

Any clue, what can be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with the lamda runtime nodejs10.x.

It was not able to find cfn-response module.

Changing `var response = require('cfn-response')` to `var response = require('./cfn-response')` fixed the issue.